# Can the Thorn Whip cantrip lift the target 10 feet into the air?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, forced-movement, falling

Can the *thorn whip* cantrip lift the target 10 feet into the air?

I can’t find any reason that casting *thorn whip* from above wouldn’t cause an extra d6 of falling damage.

This isn’t that difficult to achieve with a roof of the right height and some form of spider climb.

Comment: We tend to play on a grid but sometimes I place a mini on a die to indicate altitude.  A d6 where each pip is 5’ usually works.

Comment: Other questions about *thorn whip*'s ability to pull a creature: [Can you choose to not pull with the Thorn Whip spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70314/can-you-choose-to-not-pull-with-the-thorn-whip-spell), [Does immunity to piercing damage make you immune to the pull effect of the Thorn Whip spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174328/does-immunity-to-piercing-damage-make-you-immune-to-the-pull-effect-of-the-thorn)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## It can, if you are also in the air.

From the spell description of [Thorn Whip](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip), emphasis mine:

> ...if the creature is Large or smaller, you **pull the creature up to 10 feet closer to you**

If you are an Aarakocra Druid, and you are airborne,  You could pull the target 10 feet closer to you, in the air, and drop them to inflict falling damage.

Comment: Also works if the caster is standing, say, on a platform high above the target.

Comment: Do you need to be able to lift their body weight for this to work?

Comment: The restriction is that the spell allows for pulling the creature if the creature is Large or smaller.

Comment: @MarkWells - No, the spell does the pulling. There's no strength check involved.